Как сделать так, чтобы дата в столбце В были на 7 дней позже, чем в столбце А?
Мне нужно сделать в таблице Excel дату таким образом, 
чтобы дата в столбце В были на 7 дней позже, чем в столбце А.
Например:




A
B




1
01.12
08.12



Есть ли какая-нибудь формула для этого.

переведите, пожалуйста, текст вопроса (нажав [edit] ниже текста вопроса) на русский язык

Заголовок должен быть другой. Например: вычисляемый столбец (типа - дата) в Excel.

Очень просто:
[B1]=A1+7

В Excel даты задаются числами так, что единица равна одному дню.
